# Error when including <boost/shared_ptr.hpp> in iOS pre-compiled header file

Tags: c++, ios, boost, shared-ptr, precompiled-headers

I'm developing an iOS app and am using the shared-pointer from the Boost library. My app is a little chunky, so I've been trying to lean it up. I think moving this line:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

From individual files to the pre-compiled header file will save me some space since I heard every include of shared_ptr recompiles a different version and it's unclear whether the compiler is removing the duplicates.

When I move this line to the pch file I get a ton of compile-time errors, most of which are:

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'boost'
```

I've changed the .pch file to be a sourcecode.cpp.h file in its info, but that hasn't helped.

Thoughts?

EDIT: Just verified that there are in fact duplicate copies of the compiled shared_ptr in my binary!

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you #include shared_ptr in all your source files or in a single header. This will not cause multiple instances of the shared_ptr code in your binary. What causes multiple copies is that you used shared_ptr for multiple types. e.g. `shared_ptr<int>` and `shared_ptr<double>`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you included Boost headers in a .m file or .mm files? Because in the first case the compiler will use Objective-C, in the second case Objective-C++.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have C or ObjC sources in your project.

In that case:

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#endif
```

Xcode (by default) creates a prefix for every language/dialect in your project, and if it doesn't, it's still manually `#include`d. Unfortunately, moving a header to a pch could only *add* duplicates. It could reduce your build times, however.